# Convert Teradata to Bigquery(GCP) . DAY() TO SECOND

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to convert the `DAY() TO SECOND` function in teradata to GCP sql.
Can someone help me convert this?

```
 AVERAGE(((run_end_dttm - run_start_dttm )DAY(4) TO SECOND )) AS elapsed_time,
```

Comment: Hi Zuffido, as Bigquery doesn't support `INTERVAL` datatype in comparison to Teradata, would you expect to subtract the data in the same format i.e. `9999 23:59:59.999999` as the native Teradata `DAY(4) TO SECOND` function returns?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Yes, I want to subtract it and take an avg in similar to INTERVAL datatype.

Comment: Does the answer being provided helped you in the current research or any other concerns/doubts still exist?

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned Bigquery doesn't support `INTERVAL` data type what actually Teradata `DAY(4) TO SECOND` [function](https://docs.teradata.com/r/WurHmDcDf31smikPbo9Mcw/8m7WNvErciGcT5Uas9FfTQ) returns.

If your aim stands to get an interval difference between two timestamps in the compliant to Teradata output format i.e. `day hour:minute:second.millisecond` you might consider to write your own Bigquery [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) function which will afford this transformation.

Below I'm sharing Bigquery function prototype for this kind of conversion, leveraging some of the [Timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) and [Time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) built-in functions:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  time_conv(t1 timestamp,
    t2 timestamp) AS ((
    SELECT
      FORMAT( '%d %d:%d:%d.%d', ABS(day), EXTRACT(hour
        FROM
          time(second)), EXTRACT(minute
        FROM
          time(second)), EXTRACT(second
        FROM
          time(second)), EXTRACT(millisecond
        FROM
          time(second)) ) AS output
    FROM
      UNNEST([STRUCT( TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t1,t2, day) AS day,
          TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t1,t2, second)) AS second )]) ));
WITH
  `example` AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP("2021-10-19 21:45:21") AS t1,
    TIMESTAMP("2021-10-15 18:17:56") AS t2 )
SELECT
  time_conv(t1,
    t2)
FROM
  example
```

You can also tweak Bigquery [FORMAT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string) block getting the desirable output.

Comment: Hi, yes this is learning but I want to do it without creating any function or whatsoever. Basically, I just want to query it from the DB.

Comment: Basically the query remains in the function body operating with two timestamps(`t1`,`t2`) residing in the temporary table `example` and producing the interval difference in the desired format. The UDF injection simplifies the complex queries giving more flexibility and visibility and I presumed it would be useful in your current task. Do you have any particular concerns about this solution? Having more doubts take a chance to extend the original question.